# Java generics instead of narrowing in typical case

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance

I have got question about case below. I have got family `class Animal,` and two children classes `Dog` and `Cat`. `Dog` has `bark()` method, Cat has `meow()` method. In main class i have got `List<Animal>`, that contains both dogs and cats. I want for each dog from the list use method `.bark()`. I know that i can do it by using

```
for (Animal animal : listOfAnimals) { 
    if(animal instanceOf Dog) {
        ((Dog)animal).bark()
    }
}
```

But is it somehow possible to use generics in `Animal, Dog, Cat` classes so that not to use narrowing, but compiler will automatically know that specific animal is a type of `Cat or Dog` (i mean i want to use `animal.bark()`)?

```
class Animal {
    private String name;
    
    public Animal(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```
class Dog extends Animal{
    
    public Dog(String name){
        super(name);
    }

    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("Woof!");
    }
}
```

```
class Cat extends Animal{
    
    public Cat(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void meow() {
        System.out.println("Meow!");
    }
}
```

```
public class Main {public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Animal> listOfAnimals = new ArrayList<>;
    listOfAnimals.add(new Dog("Buddy"));
    listOfAnimals .add(new Cat("Whiskers"));
    listOfAnimals .add(new Dog("Max"));
    for (Animal animal : listOfAnimals) {
        ((dog)animals).bark;
    }
}
```

Comment: No.  There is no way to apply generics to different elements of a single List.  One small shortcut you can take, however, is:  `if (animal instanceof Dog dog) dog.bark();`

Comment: Why do you want to have a list of animals? I think in your case it is enough to have a list of dogs and fill it with dogs initially.

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my head, you could:

- implement the `bark()` method in all `Animal`s as a no-op (does nothing) and is only overridden in `Dog`s
- however, anyone could override that method and then you can have a `Fish` that barks.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to use a more generic method (not to be confused with Generics), for example `speak()`, that each child class overrides with its own implementation.

```
class Animal {
    private String name;

    public Animal(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void speak() {}
}
class Dog extends Animal{

    public Dog(String name){
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("Woof!");
    }
}
class Cat extends Animal{

    public Cat(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("Meow!");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Animal> listOfAnimals = new ArrayList();
        listOfAnimals.add(new Dog("Buddy"));
        listOfAnimals.add(new Cat("Whiskers"));
        listOfAnimals.add(new Dog("Max"));
        for (Animal animal : listOfAnimals) {
            animal.speak();
        }
    }
}
```

From there, if you are only wanting to call the method from instances of `Dog`, you can filter the list first such as:

```
listOfAnimals.stream().filter(Dog.class::isInstance).forEach(Animal::speak);
```

Comment: This is the classic solution using inheritance, I wonder if the OP's actual use case is different for some reason though.

Comment: Agreed, without more information on the specific use case, I would opt for the classic solution.